# Adobe XD <circle> to <path>

Tags: svg, path, adobe-xd

I'm working on a project and I cannot figure out how I can turn the `<circle>` into a `<path>` when I export an icon I created in Adobe XD.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 731 731"><defs><style>.a{fill:none;stroke:#15151c;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-width:100px;stroke-dasharray:220;}</style></defs><path class="a" d="M315.5,0C489.746,0,631,141.254,631,315.5S489.746,631,315.5,631,0,489.746,0,315.5,141.254,0,315.5,0Z" transform="translate(50 50)"/></svg>
```

---

I want only fill..
and stroke-width:100px;stroke-dasharray:220 in path.

Comment: I don't get it. The is a <path> in your code and no <circle>, what exactly do you want?

Answer (score 2):

*Right click* on the shape and select *Convert to Path* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd>)

And then export to svg.

[image]

That worked for me :)